# getBoundingClientRect (); coordinates are all the same

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery draggable and trying to get the coordinates of elements in getBoundingClientRect ();. Everything looks good but the console returns the same cordinates for every id.

Here's my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/progrower/orxLpfku/

Here's the js

```
 $(function() { 
 document.getElementById('save-elements').onclick = function() {

       var element_ids = [];
       var element_top = [];
       var element_left = [];

        $(".makeMeDraggable").each(function() {

        var myposition = $(this).position();
            element_ids = $(this).attr('id');
            element_top = myposition.top;
            element_left = myposition.left;


             console.log(element_ids);
             console.log(element_top);
             console.log(element_left);
         });           

    };
});
```

Here's the html

```
  <section class="columns clear">
      <div class="wideBox">
         <h1>Application Record Book</h1>
           <button id="save-elements">Save locations</button>
      </div>
 <img id="trashcan" src="images/trashcan.png" alt="Trash" />
 <div id="wrapper" style="min-height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div class="makeMeDraggable" id="number1"> </div>
     <div class="makeMeDraggable" id="number2"> </div>
       <div class="makeMeDraggable" id="number3"> </div>
        <div class="makeMeDraggable" id="number4"> </div>
 </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: You're getting the bounds for one element (`#wrapper`), then using those bounds over and over. What am I missing? What change are you expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to get each of the red boxes coordinates. My fiddle is broke. It worked before I saved it.

Comment: You'll get more help if the problematic code is here in the question. Otherwise, it'll get closed fairly soon.

Comment: Ok I thought the fiddle was all that was needed. Sorry. I'm trying to sort out the fiddle being broke.

Comment: I think I got it.   https://jsfiddle.net/progrower/orxLpfku/4/